# Unable to connect to snappydata store with spark-shell command

Tags: snappydata

SnappyData v0.5

My goal is to start a "spark-shell" from my SnappyData install's /bin directory and issue Scala commands against existing tables in my SnappyData store.

I am on the same host as my SnappyData store, locator, and lead (and yes, they are all running).

To do this, I am running this command as per the documentation here:

[Connecting to a Cluster with spark-shell](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/connectingToCluster/)

**~/snappydata/bin$ spark-shell --master local[*] --conf snappydata.store.locators=10.0.18.66:1527 --conf spark.ui.port=4041**

I get this error trying to create a spark-shell to my store:

> [TRACE 2016/08/12 15:21:55.183 UTC GFXD:error:FabricServiceAPI 
>   tid=0x1] XJ040 error occurred while starting server :
>   java.sql.SQLException(XJ040): Failed to start datab
>   ase 'snappydata', see the cause for details.
>   java.sql.SQLException(XJ040): Failed to start database 'snappydata',
>   see the cause for details.
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(SQLExceptionFactory40.java:124)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Util.java:110)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Util.java:136)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java:245)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java:3380)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.(EmbedConnection.java:450)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.(EmbedConnection30.java:94)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.(EmbedConnection40.java:75)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Driver40.java:95)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:351)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:219)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(InternalDriver.java:195)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(AutoloadedDriver.java:141)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.fabricservice.FabricServiceImpl.startImpl(FabricServiceImpl.java:290)
>           at com.pivotal.gemfirexd.internal.engine.fabricservice.FabricServerImpl.start(FabricServerImpl.java:60)
>           at io.snappydata.impl.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.scala:32)
>
> Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to
>   contact a Locator service (timeout=5000ms). Operation either timed out
>   or Locator does not exist. Configured                      list of
>   locators is "[dev-snappydata-1(null):1527]".
>           at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.internal.membership.jgroup.GFJGBasicAdapter.getGemFireConfigException(GFJGBasicAdapter.java:533)
>           at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TCPGOSSIP.sendGetMembersRequest(TCPGOSSIP.java:212)
>           at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.PingSender.run(PingSender.java:82)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm! I assume you are trying the Spark-shell from your desktop and connecting to the cluster in AWS? 
Not sure this is going to work because the local JVM launched by spark-shell will attempt to connect to the p2p cluster in Snappydata which is not likely to work.

Snappy-shell on the other hand merely uses the JDBC client to connect (and, hence will work).

And, you cannot use the locator client port (1527), anyway. See [here](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata#quick-start-with-scalasparksnappy-programming)

Can you try with `snappydata.store.locators=10.0.18.66:10334`  NOT 1527 as the port ? Unlikely this will work but worth a try.

Maybe there is a way to open up all ports and access to these nodes on AWS. Not recommended for production, though.

I am curious for other responses from the engg team. 
Until then, you may have to start the spark-shell from within the network (AWS node).

Comment: Hi jags,  I am in a PuTTY shell.  All of it is attempted on the same host in AWS.

Comment: Yes!  It was an incorrect port and the correct port was 10334