# Can't connect to snappydata store in python

Tags: python, snappydata

I am running the docker image for snappydata v0.9.  From inside that image, I can run queries against the database.  However, I cannot do so from a second server on my machine.

I copied the python files from snappydata to the installed pyspark (editing snappysession to SnappySession in the imports) and (based on the answer to [Unable to connect to snappydata store with spark-shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38921733/unable-to-connect-to-snappydata-store-with-spark-shell-command/38926794#38926794)), I wrote the following script (it is a bit of cargo-cult programming as I was copying from the python code in the docker image -- suggestions to improve it are welcome):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappyContext
from pyspark.storagelevel import StorageLevel
SparkContext._ensure_initialized()

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test")  \
                            .master("local[*]") \
                            .config("snappydata.store.locators", "localhost:10034") \
                            .getOrCreate() 

spark.sql("SELECT col1, min(col2) from TABLE1")
```

However, I get a traceback with:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Table or view not found: TABLE1
```

I have verified with wireshark that my program is communicating with the docker image (TCP follow stream shows the traceback message and a scala traceback).  My assumption is that the permissions in the snappydata cluster is set wrong, but grepping through the logs and configuration did not show anything obvious.

How can I proceed?

-------- Edit 1 ------------

The new code that I am running (still getting the same error), incorporating the suggestions for the change in the config and ensuring that I get a SnappySession is:

```
from pyspark.sql.snappy import SnappySession
snappy = SnappySession.builder.appName("test")  \
                              .master("local[*]") \
                              .config("spark.snappydata.connection", "localhost:1527") \
                              .getOrCreate() 

snappy.sql("SELECT col1, min(col2) from TABLE1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your config to the following -

.config("spark.snappydata.connection", "localhost:1527")

The 'snappydata.store.locators' property is no more there in 0.9. 
You can refer the docs here - https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata/blob/master/docs/deployment.md#connectormode

Comment: As mentioned above, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to create a [SnappySession](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/#how-to-use-python-to-create-tables-and-run-queries) to access the Snappy managed Tables. 
Something like this ....

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test")  \
                        .master("local[*]") \
                        .config("spark.snappydata.connection", "localhost:1527") \
                        .getOrCreate() 
snappy = SnappySession(spark)
snappy.sql("SELECT col1, min(col2) from TABLE1")
```

Comment: I get TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable.  See my edit for the improved code.